# Ordinary Differential Equation (1°ord.), positive or negative constant when solving Cauchy problem?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, cauchy-problem

I have this easy ODE:
*EDIT*:
 $$y'(x)=2\sqrt{y(x)}, \\y(0)=1$$ 
(OLD:
$y' = (x - 2)/2;$
$y(0) = 1$)

The general integral/solution is

$\sqrt{y} = x + c$, so $y= (x + c)^2$

Substituting the initial conditions I get
$1 = c^2$

Now, the question is: should I use $c=+1$ or $c=-1$, or both? And why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the IVP:

$$\begin{cases} y'(x)=\frac{x-2}{2} \\ y(0)=1 \end{cases} $$

Solving it via the method separation of variables we get

$$\begin{align} \int \text{d}y &=\int \frac{x-2}{2} \text{d}x \\
\Rightarrow y(x)&=\frac{x^2}{4}-x+c \end{align} $$

Now solving for the constant $c$ we get $$1=y(0)=c$$
and therefore $c=1$. The solution of the IVP is finally

$$y(x)=\frac{x^2}{4}-x+1.$$

You didn't compute the integral correctly. Generally there should be no quadratic constant $c$ since we just add a single $c$ as the integral constant. Therefore we can determine $c$ uniquely by the initial value if  Picard-Lindelöf/Cauchy-Lipschitz is applicable to our IVP. There can't be two different solutions of such an IVP.

Comment: Ops, you are right! I meant the case when I have, for example, $rad(y)=x+c$, then I have $y=(x+c)^2$. When solving Cauchy problem it is: $1=c^2$. The particular solution will be $y(x)=(x+-1)^2$ (two functions) or what else?

Comment: @Gianmi Do you mean $y'(x)=x+c$? Okay, then solving this we get $y(x)=\int x+c ~\text{d}x=\frac{x^2}{2}+cx+C$ where $C$ denotes the integral constant. Plugging in the initial value we get $1=y(0)=C$ and therefore the solution is $$y(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+cx+1$$
where $c \in \mathbb{R}$. For each specific $c$ we have an ODE that has exactly one solution.  But I think I get what you mean. See the next comment.

Comment: @Gianmi Take the ODE $$y'(x)=2\sqrt{y(x)}, y(0)=1$$ then by solving this we get
$$\int \frac{\text{d}y}{2 \sqrt{y} }=\int \text{d} x \Rightarrow \sqrt{y(x)}=x+c$$
By squaring this we get the solution $$y(x)=(x+c)^2.$$ Now plugging in the initial value we get $1=y(0)=c^2$ and get what you have said. So we get the solutions $y(x)=(x-1)^2$ and $y(x)=(x+1)^2$ which are both correct. This can be seen by plugging in the equation above. The solution isn't unique. Also notice that Picard-Lindelöf can not be applied in this case.

Comment: Ok, I get it! Thanks for the help and sorry for some incomprehension :)

Comment: @Gianmi No problem, glad I could help :) Actually this is a good question and one can see in such examples that ODEs, which don't fulfill Picard-Lindelöf, can be quite nasty since we might lose our uniqueness.